# Navigation Bar not working

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have just installed M 2.4.3,
I have something wrong with the Navbar,
it's not showing at all except for the checkout page!!

[image]
not showing the nav bar

[image]
showing the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

Please check your page layout it may be `1-column` instead of `2columns-left`.

For the categories page, you can change the layout from admin too.